# Using VirtualBox/VMWare to deploy software to multi sites?

Tags: deployment, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm currently evaluating the feasibility of using VirtualBox (or VMWare) to deploy the follow project to 10 sites

- Windows XP
- MSSQL 2005 Express Edition with Advanced Services
- JBoss to run 1 in-house software that mostly query master data (customers/products) and feed to other software

Why I want to do this ? Because the IT staffs in my 10 sites are not capable enough and the steps taken to setup those "in-house project" are also complicated

What are the cons I can forsee ?

1. Need extra power to run that virtualbox instance
2. The IT staffs won't be much knowledgeable 'bout how to install the stuffs
3. Cost (license for VirtualBox in commercial environment as well as extra OS license)

I really seek your inputs on the pro/con of this approach, or any links that I can read further

Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably better to ask on Server Fault (http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Hi, so I should just make a duplicate question there or is there anyway to move the question from here to there ? Thanks

Comment: Just duplicate the question for now.